# copy and delete data from one table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I used this code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","willy","12345","mop");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO nominated select * from student where regno = '$_POST[regno]'";
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
header("location:form5_1.php");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and this copies the content from one table to another, how do I move ( delete from current table and move to another table ) ??

Comment: There is no "move" command in sql. You `INSERT` into one table, then `DELETE` from the other. As well, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Is the reason you don't use the `DELETE` statement to prevent new records to be inserted at the time between the statement executions?

Comment: @MarcB: I dnt mind about vulnerability issues buddy, This is only for my project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Copy the record

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO nominated select * from student where regno = ".intval($_POST["regno"]);
```

2) Delete the original one

```
$sql2="DELETE from student where regno = ".intval($_POST["regno"]);
```

Execute both queries. Remember to sanitize your POST variable before doing so.

**Edit:**

You asked how to execute both of them, here is how you can do that using your own code

```
$sql1="INSERT INTO nominated select * from student where regno = ".intval($_POST["regno"]);
if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql1))
{
 // your error checking here
}
else
{
    $sql2="DELETE from student where regno = ".intval($_POST["regno"]);
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql2)
    {
      // your error checking here
    }
}
```

Comment: Would u mind telling me how to execute both the queries , I'm new to php ....

heres my complete code 


http://pastebin.com/DDvXgqw8

Comment: Can you please remove your code from this comment and append it to your question so its more readable? I'd be glad to assist

Comment: Thank u :) Working like a charm :) :)

Answer (score 0):

A MOVE SQL statement doesn't exist. You must insert the desire record into the new table and delete it from the old one.